# Ionic 4 - How to use tabs?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have tabs module with the following structure/code:

tabs.router.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                outlet: 'home',
                component: HomePage
            },
            {
                path: 'chats',
                component: ChatsPage,
                outlet: 'chats'
            },
            {
                path: 'notifications',
                component: NotificationsPage,
                outlet: 'notifications',
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab label="HOME" icon="list-box" href="">
    <ion-router-outlet stack name="home"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="CHATS" icon="list-box" href="chats">
    <ion-router-outlet stack name="chats"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="NOTES" icon="list-box" href="notifications">
    <ion-router-outlet stack name="notifications"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

When I click chats - I get:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'notifications'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'notifications'
```

why?

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your routs also

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
```

this is the html code

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab label="HOME" icon="list-box" href="/tabs/(home:home)">
    <ion-router-outlet stack name="home"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="CHATS" icon="list-box" href="/tabs/(chats:chats)">
    <ion-router-outlet stack name="chats"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="NOTES" icon="list-box" href="/tabs/(notifications:notifications)">
    <ion-router-outlet stack name="notifications"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs'`

Answer (score 0):

**Router:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'home',
                outlet: 'home',
                component: HomePage
            },
            {
                path: 'chats',
                component: ChatsPage,
                outlet: 'chats'
            },
            {
                path: 'notifications',
                component: NotificationsPage,
                outlet: 'notifications',
            }
        ]
    },{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/(home:home)'   
    }
];
```

**Template:**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab label="HOME" icon="list-box" href="/tabs/(home:home)">
    <ion-router-outlet stack name="home"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="CHATS" icon="list-box" href="/tabs/(chats:chats)">
    <ion-router-outlet stack name="chats"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="NOTES" icon="list-box" href="/tabs/(notifications:notifications)">
    <ion-router-outlet stack name="notifications"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```